# IIS 7 Website organization

Tags: iis, iis-7, configuration

I have an IIS 7.5 webserver with many web sites. Right now when I expand the Sites root node in IIS I see all of them. Isn't there a way to put them into "categories" or different folders? So for example I would want to see "Sites for customer 1", "Sites for customer 2" etc. when I expand the root Sites node in the IIS Management Console. It would be much easier to find the website I'm looking for.
I need many different websites in one category because of different host header bindings.

Is there an elegant way to accomplish this? (apart from adding more than one host header bindings to a single website, and then handling it with URL rewriting)